# Not getting email from walmart labs after registration

Tags: walmart-api

I am not getting email after registering to the walmart labs for using their API's

I did the registration from here
https://developer.walmartlabs.com/member/register

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question which should be asked to the supplier of the api.